# Riotjs data from child tag to parent tag

Tags: riot.js

I have looked lot similar questions, but still have difficulties getting it done. Try-d observable-s but messing up somewhere and cant get it done. new to riotjs still

in child tag i have a function that pushes data to a list:

```
<make-list>
...lots of html...
<script>
    var piclist = []; --after first function run this list has data
    ....
    done: function (e, data) {
                        piclist.push(data.result);
                    }
    ...
</script>
</make-list>
```

and in parent data i want to access it in a function

```
<main>
...lots of html..
<script>
riot.mount('make-list')

and i wana use that piclist = []; list here inside a function

</script>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done this way with using mixin. Maybe it's not the right way, but it works.

```
<main>
...lots of html..
<script>
riot.mount('make-list')

var piclist = [];
riot.mixin(piclist)


</script>

</main>
<make-list>
  ... lots of html ...
  <script>
    ...
      done: function (e, data) {
         piclist.push(data.result);
      }
    ...
  </script>
</make-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have the `make-list` tag create list items for a list that is displayed by `main` and `make-list` is to be a child of `main`.

You are using `riot.mount('make-list')` within the parent tag. That is at least very unusual: It actually triggers all `make-list` tags on the page to be mounted. Why not go with the riot way and add it within the html part of the parent, like this?

```
<main>
  ... lots of html ...
  <make-list opts={piclist} />

  <script>
    this.piclist = [];
  </script>
</main>
```

The opts allow you to pass data to the child (in this case the reference to the list). You can access that within the child tag like so:

```
<make-list>
  ... lots of html ...
  <script>
    ...
      done: function (e, data) {
        this.opts.piclist.push(data.result);
      }
    ...
  </script>
</make-list>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this is not what am looking for. 
make-list.tag makes a list of items, what i need in my main.tag function... 
i need to pass data from child tag to parent tag. 
The way you show, data wont pass from child tag to parent tag... says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'piclist' of undefined(…)

Comment: Well technically, you wouldn't pass data from the child to the parent, you'd pass a reference from the parent to the child so that both can access the data. Perhaps the error you are getting is because of the other parts of the `make-list` script part. Maybe this doesn't refer to the actual tag. Try setting var `tag = this` in the beginning of the script part and then use `tag.opts` instead of `this.opts`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RiotComponent](https://github.com/NawaMan/RiotComponent). It enable communication between elements in an intuitive way.